# error CS4032 When developing QnA bot C#

Tags: c#, azure, chatbot

I am trying to get my bot the greet the user by sending the first message "Hello user how are you?".

This is my current code:

```
 private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
        {
            if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
            {
                // Implement user deletion here
                // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
                // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
                // Not available in all channels

                ConnectorClient client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));

                var reply = message.CreateReply();

                reply.Text = "Hello user how are you?";

                await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
            }
```

and this is the error I receive:

```
Controllers\MessagesController.cs(55,17): error CS4032: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<Activity>'. [D:\home\site\wwwroot\Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\wwwroot\.\Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\wwwroot\.\.\\"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The error is telling you **exactly** what you need to do. You are using `await` and the  `HandleSystemMessage` method is not marked as `async`. What's the mistery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HandleSystemMessage must be async and return type must be Task in order to use await inside. Also you need to change the code calls for HandleSystemMessage too. If the calling method is async, you need to call like await HandleSystemMessage. If it's not, you need to wait for it.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I have now: 
`private async Task Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
        {...
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {            
                            ConnectorClient client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
                            var reply = message.CreateReply();
                            reply.Text = "Hello user how are you?";
                            await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);`

how do I go about calling it like await HandleSystemMessage

Comment: Where do you call HandleSystemMessage? Post the calling method please.

Comment: `public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
        {
            // check if activity is of type message
            if (activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);`

Comment: then just call like 

`await HandleSystemMessage(activity);`

Comment: So like this?:

`ConnectorClient client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
                            var reply = message.CreateReply();
                            reply.Text = "Hello user how are you?";
                            await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                            await HandleSystemMessage(activity);`

Comment: No.
`public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity) { 
// check if activity is of type message 
if (activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message) { 
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog()); 
} else { 
await HandleSystemMessage(activity); 
} 
return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174049/discussion-between-l-full-and-burak-sarica).